# How can I disable and enable Office 365 apps for all users at once using powershell?

Tags: powershell, office365

I've found scripts on Microsoft's documentation that show how to (for this example) disable Yammer for an individual user:

```
$UPN = "someone@domain.com"
$LicenseDetails = (Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN).Licenses
ForEach ($License in $LicenseDetails) {
    $DisabledOptions = @()
    $License.ServiceStatus | ForEach {
        If ($_.ProvisioningStatus -eq "Disabled" -or $_.ServicePlan.ServiceName -like "*YAMMER*") { 
            $DisabledOptions += "$($_.ServicePlan.ServiceName)" 
        } 
    }
    $LicenseOptions = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId $License.AccountSkuId -DisabledPlans $DisabledOptions
    Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $UPN -LicenseOptions $LicenseOptions
}
```

How do I pipe something like `{Get-MsolUser}` (for everyone in my organization) or an Outlook group to this rather than just a single UPN?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with enabling intune for certain users.  It's weird that Microsoft only offers a 'disable plans' option.

I fine tuned your script above and here's a script I got to work on IT Team only, for example.  Notice that it checks the current license and only changes anything if intune is disabled.

```
$us = Get-ADGroupMember "IT Team" 

foreach($u in $us){
$username = $u.SamAccountName

$userinfo = Get-ADUser $username

$upn = $userinfo.UserPrincipalName  

write-host $upn -BackgroundColor black -foregroundcolor white

    $LicenseDetails = (Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN).Licenses
    ForEach ($License in $LicenseDetails) {
        $DisabledOptions = @()
        $License.ServiceStatus | ForEach {
       # $_.ServicePlan.ServiceName
       # $_.ProvisioningStatus
            If ($_.ProvisioningStatus -eq "Disabled") { 
                $DisabledOptions += "$($_.ServicePlan.ServiceName)" 
            } 
        }


    }

     if($DisabledOptions -like "*INTUNE_A*"){
       
            write-host "Intune disabled - enabling intune" -foregroundcolor red
            $enableintune =  $DisabledOptions | Where-Object { $_ –ne "INTUNE_A" }

            #$enableintune

            $LicenseOptions = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId $License.AccountSkuId -DisabledPlans $enableintune
            Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $UPN -LicenseOptions $LicenseOptions
           }else{
          
           write-host "Intune enabled - no changes" -foregroundcolor green
      }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you call `Get-MsolUser` without specifying `-UserPrincipalName $UPN`, it will return all users in the tenant. You could then iterate over that list, extract their `UPN` and then execute this snippet against it.